# Simpledirective not injecting.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey I was wondering could someone help me and tell me why my directives aren't running in Webstorm 9.0. Why is it not adding in my directive? I thought this would be very straight forward but it doesn't seem to be injecting it.

`enter code here` http://plnkr.co/edit/fKKS1TINMHT4yJF4c9Ol?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a plunker 
To star off you havent defined your name in the ng-app thats why your app was not working
and the script files were in different order.

http://plnkr.co/edit/2SthQC5fADsi1rdEhq3C?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', []);

    app.controller('Controller', function($scope) {
      console.log('Hi');
        $scope.customer = {
            name: 'Naomi',
            address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
        };
    })
    .directive('myCustomer', function() {
        return {
            template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
        };
    });
```

Your html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <div my-customer/>
</div>

  </body>




</html>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks very much. I wish I could have accepted both answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', ['index.html'])` to `angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])` . `index.html` is not a dependency. We are linking the `js` file to `html` file. not the other way round.

Also, please change `<html ng-app>` to  `<html ng-app='docsSimpleDirective'>` Because we have given the module name as `docsSimpleDirective` in `angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])`

Comment: So the cdn isn't working? No chance you have a link for 1.5 because I got that one from here and isn't working

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/1.5.0

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please order your script files correctly as mentioned in another answer. I missed mentioning that. angular.js comes first and then your script.js